# Data in elastic proton-proton scattering

Tags: scattering-cross-section

Hello im trying to compute the cross section of an elastic proton proton scattering in the one boson exchange model and my results do not agree at all with experiment. I don't expect a excact fit since im working on only first approximation feynman diagrams, what im trying to do is to make sense of the data and i would like to ask if there is a way to verify if the intermediate results (for example of just the pion exchange) are making sense. Do you know of any way to verify how much each boson contributes to the cross section since there are no direct experimental results of just one boson exchange? Im doing that because its easier to check everything step by step instead of just checking if the whole result is correct. Im using the Matrix Elements used in this paper to do the calculations specifically the ones on page 25. Any other tips on how to tackle this problem are also appreciated. The paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/0006014

Also i get my experimental results from here https://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/hadronic-xsections/hadron.html